# Convertir base64 a image en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, base64

Buenas estoy haciando una aplicacion web y recibo desde el frontend una imagen en base64 y la quiero convertir a imagen para poder guardarla en la carpeta storage de mi proyecto, Aqui esta el intento de de lo que tengo:

```
      $image = $request->image;  // your base64 encoded
      $extension = $this->getB64Type($image);
      $image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image);
      $file = base64_decode($image);
      $filename = 'photo-' . time() . '.' . $extension;

      $file->storeAs('photos', $filename);
```

Comment: Te manda algún error?

Comment: Si, me dice que estoy tratando de usar el metodo storeAs con un objeto de tipo String